# CreateIdentityAsync calling FindByIdAsync multiple times

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity, asp.net-identity-2

I'm using ASP.NET Identity 2.0 with a custom store of my own.
I'm noticing that store operations are inefficiently called multiple times, notably upon log in.

Here is my sign in code (pretty much what's included with the default template):

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public async Task<ActionResult> LogIn(LogInModel model) 
{
    if(model!=null && (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.Email) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.Password)))
    {
        model.DisplayValidationMessages=true;
        if(ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            BaseApplicationUser user=await UserManager.FindAsync(model.Email,model.Password);
            if(user!=null)
            {
                await SignInAsync(user,model.RememberMe);
                return Redirect((model.ContinueUrl??"/")+"#"+model.State.UrlEncode());
            }

            model.ErrorMessage="Those credentials are invalid, please try again";
        }
    }

    return View(model);
}

protected async Task SignInAsync(BaseApplicationUser user,bool isPersistent)
{
    AuthenticationManager.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);
    AuthenticationManager.SignIn(
        new AuthenticationProperties { IsPersistent=isPersistent },
        await user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager)
    );
}
```

My user is extended as follow:

```
public class BaseApplicationUser:User
{
    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<BaseApplicationUser> manager)
    {
        // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
        ClaimsIdentity userIdentity=await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this,DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);

        // Add custom user claims here

        return userIdentity;
    }
}
```

ConfigureAuth:

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
{
    [...]

    // Configure the db context and user manager to use a single instance per request
    //app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);
    app.CreatePerOwinContext<BaseApplicationUserManager>((_options,_context) => BaseApplicationUserManager.Create(usersStore,_options,_context));
    app.CreatePerOwinContext<BaseApplicationRoleManager>((_options,_context) => BaseApplicationRoleManager.Create(rolesStore,_options,_context));

    // Enable the application to use a cookie to store information for the signed in user
    app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions {
        AuthenticationType=DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
        LoginPath=new PathString("/Authentication/LogIn"),
        CookieSecure=CookieSecureOption.Always,
        CookieHttpOnly=true,
        Provider=new CookieAuthenticationProvider {
            OnValidateIdentity=SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<BaseApplicationUserManager,BaseApplicationUser>(
                TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
                (_manager,_user) => _user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(_manager)
            )
        }
    });

    // Use a cookie to temporarily store information about a user logging in with a third party login provider
    app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);

    [...]
}
```

Problems:

- Upon sign in, the user is retrieved using `BaseApplicationUser user=await UserManager.FindAsync(model.Email,model.Password);` which is absolutely normal.
- When `ClaimsIdentity userIdentity=await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this,DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);` is called, it is passed a BaseApplicationUser so it shouldn't need to call `FindByIdAsync` 3 times (!!!) on the user store as it does. This is dumbly suboptimal. In fact it should even call this, since the user object is already retrieved.

Comment: I made a "per request" cache wrapper around my IStore to work around this problem and only have 1 request actually hitting the database, but this should not happen anyway...

Comment: can you show in an answer how did you workaround this?

Comment: Done, but I'm not sure it will be of any help, since it's very specific to my implementation.

Answer (score 1):

My solution is really "implementation specific" (since I implemented my own identity stores for MongoDB, I set the cache at this level, which allows me better control than a generic solution), but if this can be of any help to anybody, I posted my source code to http://pastebin.com/MV0F4MUA

You then "call" the cache for each request by setting this is your `ConfigureAuth` method:

```
app.CreatePerOwinContext<BaseApplicationUserManager>((_options,_context) => BaseApplicationUserManager.Create(new AuthenticationProviderRequestCache<BaseApplicationUser>(authenticationProvider),_options,_context));
```

WARNING: You can't simply copy/paste my code into your solution, you need to understand it to adapt it to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

I am having same issue, after some searching(not too long because no one ever posted a proper explanation for what is going on) I ended up writing my own version of `CreateIdentityAsync` method using the original method implemented in `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core` namespace as a ref., here it is:

```
public ClaimsIdentity CreateAsync(IdentityUser user, string authenticationType)
{            
     if (user == null)
     {
          throw new ArgumentNullException("user");
     }
     ClaimsIdentity claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie, ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, ClaimTypes.Role);
     claimsIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, user.Id.ToString(), "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string"));
     claimsIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.UserName, "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string"));
     claimsIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim("http://schemas.microsoft.com/accesscontrolservice/2010/07/claims/identityprovider", "ASP.NET Identity", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string"));            
     return claimsIdentity;
}
```

But this is still a workaround till I can understand where the call to `UserStore.FindByIdAsync()` is coming from

Answer (score 0):

I just had to solve this for an older web app, so here's my solution for anyone still searching.  Look at the archived AspNet Identity source (https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetIdentity).  The reason for the three calls to `IUserStore.FindByIdAsync()` is due to `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.ClaimsIdentityFactory` passing the user id to three methods when adding claims, which in turn call `IUserStore.FindByIdAsync()`.  The thing is, in my case the calling method has the user object already with everything I need, so my solution was to override these methods to accept the user object and proceed as normal.

```
public class UserManager : Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.UserManager<Employee, int>
{
    public UserManager(IUserStore<Employee, int> store) : base(store)
    {
        ClaimsIdentityFactory = new ClaimsIdentityFactory();
    }

    ...

    public override async Task<ClaimsIdentity> CreateIdentityAsync(Employee user, string authenticationType)
    {
        if (user != null && /* user is active, etc */)
        {
            var userIdentity = await ClaimsIdentityFactory.CreateAsync(this, user, authenticationType);

            ...

            return userIdentity;
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

    ...

    public async Task<string> GetSecurityStampAsync(Employee user)
    {
        var securityStore = Store as IUserSecurityStampStore<Employee, int>;

        if (securityStore == null)
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException("User Store Not IUserSecurityStampStore");
        }

        return await securityStore.GetSecurityStampAsync(user).WithCurrentCulture();
    }

    public async Task<IList<string>> GetRolesAsync(Employee user)
    {
        var userRoleStore = Store as IUserRoleStore<Employee, int>;

        if (userRoleStore == null)
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException("User Store Not IUserRoleStore");
        }

        return await userRoleStore.GetRolesAsync(user).WithCurrentCulture();
    }

    public virtual async Task<IList<Claim>> GetClaimsAsync(Employee user)
    {
        var claimStore = Store as IUserClaimStore<Employee, int>;

        if (claimStore == null)
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException("User Store Not IUserClaimStore");
        }

        return await claimStore.GetClaimsAsync(user).WithCurrentCulture();
    }
}

public class ClaimsIdentityFactory : Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.ClaimsIdentityFactory<Employee, int>
{
    ...

    public override async Task<ClaimsIdentity> CreateAsync(Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.UserManager<Employee, int> manager, Employee user, string authenticationType)
    {
        if (manager == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("manager");
        }

        if (user == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("user");
        }

        var id = new ClaimsIdentity(authenticationType, UserNameClaimType, RoleClaimType);

        id.AddClaim(new Claim(UserIdClaimType, ConvertIdToString(user.Id), ClaimValueTypes.String));
        id.AddClaim(new Claim(UserNameClaimType, user.UserName, ClaimValueTypes.String));
        id.AddClaim(new Claim(IdentityProviderClaimType, DefaultIdentityProviderClaimValue, ClaimValueTypes.String));

        if (manager.SupportsUserSecurityStamp)
        {
            id.AddClaim(new Claim(SecurityStampClaimType, await (manager as UserManager).GetSecurityStampAsync(user).WithCurrentCulture()));
        }

        if (manager.SupportsUserRole)
        {
            IList<string> roles = await (manager as UserManager).GetRolesAsync(user).WithCurrentCulture();

            foreach (string roleName in roles)
            {
                id.AddClaim(new Claim(RoleClaimType, roleName, ClaimValueTypes.String));
            }
        }

        if (manager.SupportsUserClaim)
        {
            id.AddClaims(await (manager as UserManager).GetClaimsAsync(user).WithCurrentCulture());
        }

        return id;
    }
}
```