# ASP.NET Identity 2 and CreatePerOwinContext multiple sql calls

Tags: asp.net, sql, identity, owin

I'm question is pretty much the same as the one below, except I can reproduce with the Microsoft samples. "Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Samples -Pre"

If you install this package and then profile using MiniProfiler you'll notice that each time you do an operation related to users, duplicate statements are sent to SQL Server. It calls FindByIdAsync multiple times which in turn makes calls to the database.

By wrapping the ApplicationUserManager and DataContext in CreatePerOwinContext, it should only send the SQL once within the same request and not multiple times. I have no idea why this is happening. Below is a similar question which may assist in getting an answer, but as I said can reproduce with the sample code.

[CreateIdentityAsync calling FindByIdAsync multiple times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24111679/createidentityasync-calling-findbyidasync-multiple-times)